# How to fire a row select action for in-grid button in primeNG datatable?

Tags: primeng

I am using PrimeNG dataTable. I have a button "Show Detail" in table which is to show the row's detail in a detail container, and requires to keep the row's selected/highlighted status.

In the samples, there're only radio button and checkbox, how to fire the selection via button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized I'd better to answer my own question since afterwards I figured it out :)

Add a click trigger in html,

```
(click)='tblShowStatementPayments(dt, $event,item)
```

"dt" is defined here as an instance reference `<p-dataTable #dt [value]="statements" [responsive]="true" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="5">`

```
  tblShowStatementPayments(dt: any, event: any, stat: any) {
    dt.selectRowWithRadio(event, stat) // here is highlight the row selected

    this.operStatement = stat;
    this.statSvc.getPaymentDetailByStatementId(stat.id).subscribe(res => {
      this.operStatement.paymentDetails = res;
    }, err => {
      this.growlSvc.stickError('Failed', err);
    });
  }
```